# Mosteller's solutions to random-walk problems

Tags: probability

In Mosteller's solution to the 2D random walk problem in *Fifty Challenging Problems* he writes:

"ow many times will a particle come back to the origin? If $P$ is the probability of a return, then $1-P=Q$ is the probability of no return. The probability of exactly $x$ returns is $P^xQ$, because after each return the particle might as well be regarded as starting over. If $P$ were known, then the mean number of returns to the origin could be computed from this geometric series as $\mu = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} xP^xQ$. Looking back at Problem 4 on trials until first success, we find the mean number to be the reciprocal of the probability of success. Here a non-return to the origin terminates the series, so the mean number of of trials to first success is $1/Q$. Consequently, the mean number of successes is $1/Q - 1$."

I understand what Mosteller means that a non-return to the origin is considered a success, but I don't understand why the mean number of successes is $1/Q-1$.

Similarly, in the 3D random walk problem: "This $0.315$ is the mean number of returns to the origin per particle. Consequently, $1/Q=1+0.315$."

The following formula seems to be the probability of return to origin but is then interpreted as the mean number of returns: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[{2n \choose n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}\right]^2$.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail here? What are the "successes" that you (or Mosteller, I suppose) are referring to?

Comment: I edited the question to include a longer quote from Mosteller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand what Mosteller means that a non-return to the origin is considered a success, but I don't understand why the mean number of successes is $1/Q-1$.

It looks like Mosteller is making a mistake in conflating what constitutes the word "success" (or perhaps there's a transcription error). To be consistent, let's regard "success" as a walk that leaves its starting point and does not come return. What Mosteller is trying to communicate is:

"Here a non-return to the origin terminates the series, so the mean number of  trials to first success (**i.e. total excursions of the random walk**) is $1/Q$. Consequently, the mean number of <s>successes</s> **excursions that return to the starting point** is $1/Q - 1$."

The idea is supposed to be: if a random walk visits its starting location 10 times, then the last visit is the terminating one that ended the process because the walk left and never returned; the other 9 visits are the $n-1$ excursions that *did* return home.

> Similarly, in the 3D random walk problem: "This $0.315$ is the mean number of returns to the origin per particle. Consequently, $1/Q=1+0.315$."

This follows immediately from the $1/Q - 1 = \mathbb E[R]$ observation, where $\mathbb E[R]$ denotes the expected number of return visits.

> The following formula seems to be the probability of return to origin but is then interpreted as the mean number of returns: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[{2n \choose n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}\right]^2$.

You're right on both counts, actually; the terms inside the sum are indeed return probabilities, and summing them does indeed give the expected number of visits to the origin. This is because
\begin{align*}
  \sum \mathbb P(X_n = o) &= \sum \mathbb E \left[ 1_{X_n = o} \right] \\
&= \mathbb E \left[ \sum 1_{X_n = o} \right]
\end{align*}
and the term in the brackets on the final line counts the number of visits to state $o$.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. I think that the root of my difficult is that I interpreted "What is the chance that the particle returns to the origin?" as looking for the first return to the origin rather than the probability that it returns to the origin one or more times.